# how to check negative and positive scenarios in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing a unit test in Jest for one of the React component But in both scenarios, I'm getting a false response.

`foo.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Foo({ data }) {
  if (data === true) {
    return (
      <div className="hello" id="helloId">
        Hello
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="hi" id="hiId">
        Hi
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { Foo };
```

`foo.spec.js`:

```js
describe('check foo Component', () => {
  describe('without data', () => {
    const mount = shallow(<Foo data={false} />);
    it('data is false', () => {
      expect(mount.contains('hello')).toBeNull();
    });
  });
  describe('without data', () => {
    const mount = shallow(<Foo data={true} />);
    it('data is true', () => {
      expect(mount.contains('hello')).toBeNull();
    });
  });
});
```

In both the test cases I'm getting false. It must be true in one case and false in another. Getting error in the console

> is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

if any element is not defined.

How to write test cases for both the scenarios?

Comment: There are a bunch of errors in your code.  Where does `mountedComponent` comes from? `const mount = shallow(<Foo data={true}/>` should be run inside of the `it` block. `contains` expect an wrapper object not just a string. How is `data` passed into the render function? Instead of `contains` you should use `find('.hello')` to check if the `hello` container was rendered

Comment: in addition theres a class attribute on first div instead of className

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`foo.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Foo({ data }) {
  if (data === true) {
    return (
      <div className="hello" id="helloId">
        Hello
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="hi" id="hiId">
        Hi
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { Foo };
```

`foo.test.tsx`:

```js
import { Foo } from './foo';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('check foo Component', () => {
  it('data is false', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo data={false} />);
    expect(wrapper.contains('Hi')).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('data is true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo data={true} />);
    expect(wrapper.contains('Hello')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/50540892/foo.test.tsx
  check foo Component
    ✓ data is false (10ms)
    ✓ data is true (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 foo.tsx  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.253s, estimated 9s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/50540892